# html reset text area on frame form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to reset the text area on my submit which sends data without changing the page.

```
    <iframe name="votar" style="display:none;"></iframe>
    <form id ="myForm" action="message-process.php" method="post" target="votar">
      <?php
      echo "<input type='hidden' name='userId' value= '$sendId'>";
      ?>
        <textarea rows="5" cols="60" name="message" type="text" maxlength="255" style="font-size:10px background-color:grey;"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Send Message">
    </form>
```

Comment: *«without changing the page»*... Look for Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML form attribute `onsubmit="func()"`

And inside a Javascript script set the value of what you wish to an empty string.

Comment: function reset(){
  document.getElementById("input").value = "";
}                                                                                                                            Would that work if I include an id tag on my text area?

Answer (score 0):

This code works.

```
    <iframe name="votar" style="display:none;"></iframe>
    <form id ="myForm" action="message-process.php" method="post" target="votar" onsubmit="this.submit(); this.reset(); return false;">
      <?php
      echo "<input type='hidden' name='userId' value= '$sendId'>";
      ?>
        <textarea id ='input' rows="5" cols="60" name="message" type="text" maxlength="255" style="font-size:10px background-color:grey;"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Send Message">
    </form>
```